# How to download and install "oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip"

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ubuntu-14.04

I want to install oracle database. All the tutorial in web i have seen so far include link to download "oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip" is redirecting to the page where there is 18c only.and i search google a lot but didn't find any link to download the file. Later i download 11gR2 from this [link](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/112010-linx8664soft.html#license-lightbox) this link but i'm not finding any installing guide which can help me to install it.

N.B: OS Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Please note that Oracle is not designed nor certified for Ubuntu.  It is designed for an entirely different branch of Linux - Red Hat/Oracle/CentOS.  There are hacks available to get Oracle on Ubuntu, but that's exactly what they are -- hacks.  And even if you get it installed, every problem you face will be colored by that fact.  You'd be better off installing Oracle VirtualBox, then creating a VM that runs a certified OS.  I am typing this from my personal laptop that is running Ubuntu.  On that I have a couple of Oracle Linux VM's running different versions of Oracle database.

Comment: @EdStevens There is docker for that! Nobody in 2020 should install Oracle Database on dedicated Linux distro, at least for development purposes!

Comment: @EdStevens This is not only my opinion. Docker allows to isolate and untie from the host OS what you wanna execute. Using Docker, you can run Oracle Database almost under any Linux distro, you wish. And this answers the question, how to start up Oracle Database XE under Ubuntu. By the way, I managed to bootstrap both XE 11.2 and 18.4 simultaneously, connect to them and successfully try them out!

Answer (score 9):

1. Take the [link](http://download.xskernel.org/soft/linux-rpm/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip)! (It was taken from [this](http://download.xskernel.org/soft/linux-rpm/) ftp).
2. Next, you have to use docker for Oracle Database installation. This [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/deliver-oracle-database-18c-express-edition-in-containers) will help you.
   Two important notes:

   - As the link to the 11.2 version is dead, you have to download it manually and copy in the folder '11.2.0.2' (its the subfolder in place, where `buildDockerImage.sh` resides).
   - Then run

     `./buildDockerImage.sh -x -v 11.2.0.2`

P.s. Firstly, I built XE 18.4.0. Building Docker image took way long! The building of 11.2.0.2, took 85 seconds. So, if you see that the script is stuck somewhere, it's wise to wait. (I halted execution a few times, thinking that it had hung up...)

Comment: Links are offline

Comment: @JimWalker your link is just a landing page in which there are not any downloadable resource

Answer (score 8):

Oracle removed the links, but the files are still there.

https://download.oracle.com/otn/linux/oracle11g/xe/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/oracle11g/xe/OracleXE112_Win32.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/oracle11g/xe/OracleXE112_Win64.zip

Of course before using that direct link, you need to go to any other public download page and accept the license agreement, but after that, it works.

PS: can be found in the webarchive
http://web.archive.org/web/20210204141448/https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/xe-prior-releases.html

and try this instructions
[http://www2.hawaii.edu/~lipyeow/ics321/2015spr/installoracle11g.html](http://www2.hawaii.edu/%7Elipyeow/ics321/2015spr/installoracle11g.html)

in general, there are quite a few of them in the search engine

Answer (score 2):

Oracle 11g is a very old version; it will not be supported after this year. The 18c version is the current XE distribution. See these links for help installing:

https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/oracle-db-18c-xe-rpm-installation-on-oracle-linux-6-and-7

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/xeinl/

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/xeinl/procedure-installing-oracle-database-xe.html

Comment: How about supporting of legacy software? I have faced with exactly the same problem, as the author of this topic!

Comment: Software can only be supported for so long. 11g was supposed to end support several years ago and Oracle already extended the date. There have been at least four major releases since then, with the fifth scheduled for this year. Also, I don't believe that any recent version of Oracle (including 11g) was ever certified or supported on Ubuntu, so in that case there's nothing to extend.